# react constantly calling the API when using .map to go through the list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, state

i have setup a strapi API, and i am using react to consume that API (with Axios).

***here's what the code look like inside App.js***

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import LineCard from "./components/Linecard"
function App() {
  
  // don't mind the URL i will fix them later
  const root = "http://localhost:1337"
  const URL = 'http://localhost:1337/pick-up-lines'

  // this is the "messed up" data from strapi
  const [APIdata, setAPIdata] = useState([])

  //this is the clean data
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([])

  // the array that i will be using later to "setLines" state
  const linesFromApi = APIdata.map((line, index) => {
    const profileImage = root + line.users_permissions_user.profilePicture.formats.thumbnail.url
    const userName = line.users_permissions_user.username
    const title = line.title
    const lineBody = line.line
    const rating = line.rating
    const categories = line.categories.map((category, index) => category.categoryName)

    return {
      profileImage,
      userName,
      title,
      lineBody,
      rating,
      categories
    }

  })


  useEffect(() => {
    // calling the API with get method to fetch the data and store it inside APIdata state
    axios.get(URL).then((res) => {
      setAPIdata(res.data)
    })
    setLines(linesFromApi)
  }, [URL, linesFromApi])




  return (
    <div>
     // mapping through the lines list and rendering a card for each element
      {lines.map((line, index) => <LineCard line={line} />)}

    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

i know for sure that this is causing the problem

```js
return (
    <div>
      {lines.map((line, index) => <LineCard line={line} />)}

    </div >
  );
```

my problem is that react keeps sending GET requests constantly, and i want it to stop after the first time it has the list.

how can i do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a check in your hook so that it restricts the api call if the value is already set.
Something like this

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(lines.length === 0){
  axios.get(URL).then((res) => {
    setAPIdata(res.data)
  })
  setLines(linesFromApi)
 }
}, [URL, linesFromApi])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `key` property to the element in a map.

```
 <div>
      {lines.map((line, index) => <LineCard key={index} line={line} />)}
</div>
```

Comment: didn't help sir!